# regex multiline matching in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to filter for '**here is a sample**' and all the lines afterwards until **2 new lines**:

Here is my file (you can use it as a logfile):

```
here is a sample text
random line1


here is a sample text
random line2
random line3
random line4


should not match
random line 6


here is a sample 
random line 5
```

I tried:

```
    \r?\n?(here is a sample).*\r?\n?(.*)
```

With that I only filter the next line if I do the last part **'\r?\n?(.*)'**
again I get another line..

My question. What regex expression do I need in order to match all lines **until I see 2 new lines**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match all until you have 2 newline, but also want to match the last occurrence if there are no 2 newlines:

```
^here is a sample.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `here is a sample.*` Match literally and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n(?!\n)` Match a newline, and assert that it is not directly followed by a newline
  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxD5Ii/1)

If there should be 2 newlines present, you can use a capture group for the part that you want to keep, and match the 2 newlines to make sure that they are present.

```
^(here is a sample.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)\n\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SfWz5C/1)